# How to respect local changes when querying?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is there an "EF Core way" to consider local changes when querying a DbSet?

I'd like to respect the pattern of only calling `DbContext.SaveChanges()` once per task, but it seems like the disconnect between local state and DB state can get complicated very quickly with queries going directly to the DB.

---

Example:

I update some elements in a DbSet

```
var results = db.Entity1.Where(e => e.date > expectedDate);
foreach(var result in results){
    e.field = true;
}
```

And subsequently, query that same DbSet

```
db.Entity1.Where(e => e.field == false)
```

The second query returns the rows changed in the first block, as the query goes directly to the database without considering local changes. I'd like the second query to only return rows where `e.field == false` in both the database and locally.

Comment: Have you considered just using a local caching Database? A simple Distributed Database design is just to have one read-only local DB. But sometimes they are also given the option to puffer write requests. In Mobile Apps that design is all the rage, considering how easy it is to loose power and internet connection.

Comment: @Christopher Are you suggesting that by using a local caching database we avoid the overhead that is the reason for calling ```DbContext.SaveChanges()``` only once per task?

Comment: So you considered and found it not worth the effort. Okay. All I can give you is the usual warning: it is one call now, but will it stay that way? Features have one issues: The more you add, the more are requested. And now that you made a divergent Local state possible in one area, I would expect more requests along this line to come.

Comment: @Christopher I haven't drawn any conclusions, just trying to better understand your comment.

Comment: Note that EF does re-query the entities, but does not overwrite the local `e.field` values. What is `false` locally remains `false`.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to commit changes by logical groups, and at the same time avoid issues about querying the database and the `Local` cache, then start by loading all entities that you need to work with in the `Local` cache, work on the `Local` cache only, and finally `SaveChanges()`.

In your example, you would have this.

```
// Load entities whose date > expectedDate or whose field = false.
var result = db.Entity1.Where(e => e.date > expectedDate || e.field == false);
...
// Set field to true for entities whose date > expectedDate.
foreach (var entity in db.Entity1.Local.Where(e => e.date > expectedDate)) {
    entity.field = true;
}
...
// Get entities whose field = false.
result db.Entity1.Local.Where(e => e.field == false)
...
db.SaveChanges();
```